# How to restructure these lone headers into the second column?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I have a dataset and it looks like this:

[image]

How can I get it to look like this so that **Tennis** in A1 and **Basketball** in A5 can be placed in column B like this:

[image]

I can clean up the lone headers (Tennis and Basketball in row 1 and 5), but no idea where to even start to get those values (Tennis and Basketball) in their own rows in column B underneath the header (Group). Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this will work in `2010`:

```
B1: =IF(A1="Name","Group",IF(A2="Name","", INDEX($A$1:A1,LOOKUP(2,1/($A$1:A1="Name"),ROW($A$1:A1))-1)))
```

and fill down.

***Algorithm***

- If the adjacent cell in Column A =  "Name" then enter "Group"
- If the next cell down in column A = "Name" then leave a blank
- The lookup formula will return the row number of the last cell in column A (up to the current row of the formula) that = "Name"

  - Subtract `1` to get the row number of the group name

    - *The `1` would need to be changed to the first row number of your table in the event the table does not start in Row 1*
  - The Index function will then return the relevant group name

[image]

Answer (score -1):

How about a formula in B3 like:

```
=If(B2="Group",A1,B2)
```

Filling that down should get you what you want.

Comment: That just provides `Tennis` alll the way down.